# How to create multiple user in BIM server ? Version : 1.3.0-RC6-2014-03-14

Tags: java, ifc

I am new in BIM Server , trying to figure out how BIM server and IFC model sync together.

I made connectivity to local BIM-server from a java application. I use the default settings as described in  https://github.com/opensourceBIM/BIMserver/wiki/Setup .

Now, when I am going to create a new user it only ask for mail address , username and Access level. No password field . So, I can not do log in using that user.

"Send Password Reset" is giving the following error :
" Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25 (java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect) " .

Whether it is a BIM server version problem or I am missing something ?

I have not found any well prepared Documentation or tutorial on BIM server. My goal is to check how the BIM server can replace the ftp server that we are using now to store IFC files.

Thanks in advance
-Nazar-E-Bukhari

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this in BIM server Issues. I am posting the answer if someone is also searching for the same solution.

"It's really bad practice to have an administrator set the user's passwords. How is the administrator going to give the passwords to those users? (I agree with him, but as because I am testing it in my localhost, I have no mail server configured)

Setup a working e-mail server, or better yet, use a third party's server. For example have a look at mailgun, sendgrid or postmark."